# How to display filename under file in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am making php gallery. There is a gallery folder in which videos are stored. The videos are displayed on the page but I want name of the video to be displayed under the video itself. I tried by combining code from websites but the result isn't successful.
Please Help. Thanks in advance.

My code:

Gallery.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple PHP Video Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2-theme.css">
    <script src="3-gallery.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
  <h1>h</h1>
    <div id="vid-gallery"><?php
      // (A) GET ALL VIDEO FILES FROM THE GALLERY FOLDER
      $dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "gallery" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
      $videos = glob("$dir*.{webm,mp4,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $alt = glob("$dir*.{webm,mp4,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE);
    
      // (B) OUTPUT ALL VIDEOS
      if (count($videos) > 0) { foreach ($videos as $vid) {
        printf("<video src='gallery/%s'></video>", rawurlencode(basename($vid)));
   //I added this one from another website in code:
  $fileList = glob('gallery/*');
      foreach($fileList as $filename){
      if(is_file($filename)){
      echo("<h1>$filename;</h1>"),'<br>'; 
      }   
      }
      }}
      ?>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
/* (A) GALLERY - BIG SCREEN */
#vid-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
#vid-gallery video {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* (B) GALLERY - SMALL SCREEN */
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #vid-gallery { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto); }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #vid-gallery { grid-template-columns: auto; }
}
```

and js:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  for (let vid of document.querySelectorAll("#vid-gallery video")) {
    // (A) CLICK ON THUMBNAIL TO GO FULLSCREEN
    vid.onclick = () => {
      if (!vid.fullscreenElement) {
        vid.controls = true;
        vid.requestFullscreen();
      }
    };

    // (B) EXIT FULLSCREEN MODE
    vid.onfullscreenchange = () => {
      if (document.fullscreenElement == null) {
        vid.controls = false;
        vid.pause();
      }
    };
  }
});
```

The name of my video folder is gallery.

Result:
[Problematic Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfknB.png)

**In short: My problem is how to display each video's title (name) under it.**

Comment: As far as I can see you don't need a separate `foreach` to process the filenames. You already have the filename in `$vid` - just echo that immediately after the `<video>` tag.

Comment: @ADyson Sir I'm new to php. I didn't quite understand your correction on code. Please can you answer it and post the correct code. Consider this a request. It's a very important matter for me.

Comment: What specifically didn't you understand? It's trivial - just `echo "<h1>".$vid."</h1>";` after the printf line. You don't need the foreach loop.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot. It's working like magic. Any idea how to remove directory path and extension from name? Just name without extension.

Comment: Google already knows. Did you think of doing any research? It's not a new or rare requirement. Just google "php remove extension from filename" for example, and "php remove path from filename"

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for taking out time. I figured it out. No need to get hyper sir. :) You sure had been in the position like this somewhere in your life. Stay blessed.

Comment: I'm not hyper at all, it was just an honest question. When I don't know something, the first step is to google it. If that doesn't help, then after that maybe other people can :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ADyson and Google, I figured it out.
Just replace the `php` code:

```
  <?php
    $exten = '.mp4';
      $dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "gallery" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
      $videos = glob("$dir*.{mp4}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $alt = glob("$dir*.{webm,mp4,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE);
      if (count($videos) > 0) { foreach ($videos as $vid) {
        printf("<video src='gallery/%s'></video>", rawurlencode(basename($vid)));
     echo "<h1>".basename($vid,$exten)."</h1>";
   }}
        ?>
```

The main problem was the 2nd for each loop.
It will display each video's name (without extension and path).